# Reverse movement done with transform.RotateAround()

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a third person mobile game with the help of joysticks. I have it set up where `joystick.vertical` moves the character forward or backwards depending on where he is looking and `joystick.horizontal` turns the character. Since the camera is parented to the character the camera always stays behind the character.

Swiping across the screen rotates the camera around the player with a touch panel using `Camera.main.transform.RotateAround()` function and the `transform.LookAt()` ensures I am looking at my character always.

**My issue**: I would like when the swipe is let go the camera to return to its original position behind the character **but in a smooth motion or at a set speed moving around the player**.

**My Solution 1**: To make an empty `gameObject` parented to the character and place it in the position where I want the camera to revert back to and call this position when the mouse is let go.

```
float spanCamera = -Joystick.Horizontal;

Camera.main.transform.LookAt(rb.transform.position);
if (spanCamera != 0)
    Camera.main.transform.RotateAround(rb.position, Vector3.up, spanCamera * Time.fixedDeltaTime * spanSpeed);

else if (Input.touchCount <= 1)
{
    float var6 = var5 * Time.deltaTime;

    Camera.main.transform.position = camPos.transform.position;

    Camera.main.transform.LookAt(camLookAt.transform.position);
}
```

This piece of code moves the camera back to the start position immediately without smoothing.

**Solution 2**: use a `Vector3.MoveTowards()` instead

```
// Camera.main.transform.position = camPos.transform.position;

Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(Camera.main.transform.position, camPos.transform.position, var6);
```

This code allows me to smoothly move to the start position **in a straight line**. I want it to go around the player.

So I tried a different method where I assign a float value `1` if the camera turns right and check if the rotate button is let go and if the value is `1` within an `if` block.

```
public float axisDir;

...

else if (spanCamera == 0 && axisDir == 1)
{
    Camera.main.transform.RotateAround(rb.position, Vector3.up, -1 * Time.fixedDeltaTime * spanSpeed);
}
```

But this results in an infinite spin because I do not know how to check if the desired position has been reached.

I hope someone can help. This is quite a long post. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could have an dummy `gameObject` as a child of the player, and the camera as a child of the dummy.

That way, the camera is looking at the centre of the `gameObject`: where the player is. The camera would also rotate with the player, so it would always be behind the player.

Now, you know that when `Mathf.Approximately(dummy.transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0.0f)`, the camera is behind the player. [[1](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html)][[2](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html)]

Knowing that, you can check when the player stopped swiping and start slowly rotating it back.

```
// If the player let go and camera is not behind the player
if (!playerIsSwiping && !Mathf.Approximately(dummy.transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0.0f))
{
    // Slowly rotate until the camera is behind the player
    dummy.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: This helped a bit, in the sense that i managed to change the coding a bit to end up with an infinite loop where the camera just keeps spinning, and that is the only way i managed to make it work.

`if (spanCamera == 0 && !Mathf.Approximately(Camera.main.transform.position.y, 0.0f))
  {
   Camera.main.transform.RotateAround(camLookAt.transform.position, Vector3.up, 1f * spanSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
   
   Debug.Log("it works");
  }`

Answer (score 0):

try this buddy :

```
// Maximum turn rate in degrees per second.
 public float turningRate = 30f; 
 // Rotation we should blend towards.
 private Quaternion _targetRotation = Quaternion.identity;
 // Call this when you want to turn the object smoothly.
 public void SetBlendedEulerAngles(Vector3 angles)
 {
   _targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(angles);
 }

 private void Update()
 {
    // Turn towards our target rotation.
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, _targetRotation, turningRate * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```

i found it [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/717637/how-do-you-smoothly-transitionlerp-into-a-new-rota.html)

from my own experience using LERP works quite well, you lookin for a smooth transition, or between two points, known as interpolation, in this case linear interpolation.

Comment: i was not able to make this work, unfortunately.... and also now might be a bad time to mention that all the experience i have on unity is only a few days worth time within 2 weeks of unity tutorials